# Docker/Hibernate/PostgreSQL - Connecting container running Hibernate/SpringBoot app with a postgreSQL container not working

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, docker, spring-boot

I'm running a very simple SpringBoot app that uses Hibernate to connect to a PostgreSQL db. And running two Docker containers, one with the .war with a Tomcat image and one with a postgresql image.

This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  spring2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfileTomcat
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - datalink

  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    env_file:
      - psql.env
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - datalink

networks:
  datalink:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  database:
```

And this is the hibernate.cfg.xml in the war:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/myappdb</property>
  <property name="connection.username">admin</property>
  <property name="connection.password">pass1234</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

  <mapping class="(...).models.Employee"/>
```

So when I run the app with Eclipse in my host machine, connecting to the docker image, it works, but when I run it with Docker, using the docker compose, the endpoints that use the DB connection and Hibernate return 404.

And the most confusing part is that no Errors show up. It just says that the endpoint is not found.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the stack trace, also did you check if you can reach db from the spring2 container?

Comment: What is the easiest way to test the connection within the tomcat container? Also, it doesn't show any errors

Comment: There are many ways of checking that, use `docker exec -i -t spring2 /bin/sh` and a simple `ping db` would be enough. spring2 is the name of you container.

Comment: I tried ping db and it worked

Comment: You should provide the stack trace of the error.

Comment: This is also the problem. I don't get anything in the server log, no errors just 404. As if the method wasn't there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, it was actually a mistake I was making with Docker.

I was using the same image everytime I did `docker-compose up` so the .war file I was actually running wasn't the version I was trying to run.

What I did was simply `docker-compose build` and it worked.